# How to save text to html file unchanged (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to save/copy text from text file to html file, without or with formatting to leave the text unchanged.

Example:

```
> ❯ cat TEST.txt
TEST TEST 1 ONE TEST
234 TEST AGAIN TEST
1234 : : : TEST TEST%
```

Code:

```
with open('TEST.txt', 'r') as firstfile, open('RESULT.txt', 'a') as secondfile:
# read content from first file
for line in firstfile:
    # append content to second file
    secondfile.write(line)
```

Result:

```
    ❯ cat RESULT.txt
TEST TEST 1 ONE TEST
234 TEST AGAIN TEST
1234 : : : TEST TEST%
```

Now it worked well but when I try to save second file as HTML  it has different result where all strings copied in one.

Code:

```
with open('TEST.txt', 'r') as firstfile, open('RESULT.html', 'a') as secondfile:
# read content from first file
for line in firstfile:
    # append content to second file
    secondfile.write(line)
```

Result:

```
TEST TEST 1 ONE TEST 234 TEST AGAIN TEST 1234 : : : TEST TEST
```

But I need to copy strings unchanged from txt file to html file.

thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example? Code snippet? You've gotta include important information if you want good answers. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I've added explanations. I hope it's enough .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html to create new line

```
with open('TEST.txt', 'r') as firstfile, open('RESULT.html', 'a') as secondfile:
# read content from first file
for line in firstfile:
    # append content to second file
    secondfile.write(line + '<br/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding newlines.

```
with open('TEST.txt', 'r') as firstfile, open('RESULT.html', 'a') as secondfile:
# read content from first file
for line in firstfile:
    # append content to second file
    secondfile.write("\n" + line)
```

Comment: It doesn't work when you look at the HTML  file via browser.
Still whole text in one line.